# Will fragmentation of a virtual machine's disk also cause host OS disk fragmentation?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, defragment

I run a number of virtual machines using VMWare Player on top of host Windows 7 OS. Let's say I am using the VMs for everything from web browsing to actual work, file transfer, etc. for a long period. Will this cause fragmentation within the host Windows 7 OS?

Comment: No;  The virtual HDD file for virtual machine is either a single file or multiple files on the actual physical storage device.  The only actual file fragmentation that exists would be the fragmentation of those files.

Comment: @op, note that virtual filesystem fragmentation is not the same as fragmentation on the physical disk, so you will get less value from defraging a virtual file system. The disks SCAN and SEEK operations will not be reduced as a result of the defrag, since the whole virtual volume is in a single file. There may be some reduction in scanning and seeking, but not nearly what you would see on a highly fragmented physical disk.

Comment: @FrankThomas The VMs I create have the file system distributed into several files, there's an option for this when creating a VM with VMWare software. However I am more interested in keeping the host healthy and whenever a guest gets fragmented I'm thinking of saving the contents and restoring an earlier snapshot with the virtual disk in better shape.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether the virtual filesystem is one file or a dozen, so I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish. I have no idea why you would want to do as you suggest. Virtual fragmentation is NOT the same as physical fragmentation, so I recommend you just defrag the host drives occasionally, and leave it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types of fragmentation that can occur:

1. Fragmentation of the guest file system.  This would occur if you perform activities in the guest that would normally lead to fragmentation on a physical machine.  You would defragment this by running a defragmentation utility from within the guest.
2. Fragmentation within the VM's `.vmdk` file.  This occurs if you use a sparse virtual disk and the virtual disk grows out of order.  If, for example, the guest writes to blocks in a non-consecutive order (e.g. block 100, then block 50, then block 75), if those are newly added blocks, they might be added to the end of the `.vmdk` file in that same non-consecutive order.  You would defragment this by asking VMware Workstation to defragment the virtual disk file (in VMware Workstation 12, this is under VM > Settings > Hardware > Hard Disk > Disk utilities > Defragment).
3. Fragmentation of the host file system.  You would defragment this by running a defragmentation utility on the host OS.

It's not necessarily true that fragmentation in one type would cause fragmentation in another type.  For example:

- The `.vmdk` file could grow and be internally fragmented (type 2), but the host file system could be sufficiently empty to allow the `.vmdk` file to grow without fragmentation.
- If most of the `.vmdk` file is already allocated (i.e., it is not likely to grow any more), then fragmentation types 2 and 3 would not get any worse, but it would still be possible for the guest to increase fragmentation of its own file system (type 1).