# How to defragment Virtual Machine in order to optimise virtual HD backups?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, backup, vmware, defragment

I've got the following setup:

- a virtual machine with a virtual HDD at 160GB split over around 50 files (it's a VMWare VM, so I'm talking about VMDK files)
- after working in the VM for some hours, my daily backup will copy all 50 file, because they all have modifications

My question is this:

- Is there a tool to "defragment" the windows file system in a way to keep the busy files roughly together?
- (The idea is that fewer HDD files are modified in order to improve backup performance)

My questions are **not**:

- How to defragment a HDD in general...
- How to improve backup performance in general...
- I'm not looking for suggestions on backup software...

Comment: Even if not all VMDK files have real changes the virtual machine will usually update the change date so that your file level backup will backup all of them. Have you tried what happens if you start the VM and directly shut it down? Most likely all files have been changed. For backup of VM images you need an backup program that detects file changes on block level so only the real modifications are included into the backup.

Comment: On a decent disk, I do not think it matters a whole lot about the precise location of the files.  Have you tried (with the Windows VM Off) Menu, VM, Manage Disks, Cleanup Disks?

Comment: You can automate the manage disk operations (i.e. cleanup disks) with PowerCLI.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question, and posit that your way of tackling the problem is very flawed.  Would you not be better off partitioning the VM in such a way that data which is going to be updated is on seperate partitions from data which is static?

Comment: Windows tends to be reading and writing files all the time at the most unexpected places, so all your files are going to be modified. You should use a backup program that checks the part of the file that was modified, example from Duplicity docs: "_Because duplicity uses librsync, the incremental archives are space efficient and only record the parts of files that have changed since the last backup_"

Comment: I don't think defragment isn't the right word choice here. It also sounds like this is VMWare but the question is tagged for virtualbox. You might try converting to a monolithic vmdk and then back to split files again, but my guess is that the individual vmdks will still all change when split again. You may wish to look into VMWare's Changed Block Tracking (CBT) and a backup tool that can use this information (assuming you are using ESXi).

Answer (score 2):

Take a snapshot of your VM.  This will prevent further writes to your existing `.vmdk` files, and they therefore will need to be backed up only once.  Your regular backups then would backup only your delta disks, which usually would be much smaller (at least initially).  To minimize unnecessary, future large-scale changes to the delta disks, before you take the snapshot, you should:

- [Defragment your guest file system](https://superuser.com/a/1006941/).
- Wipe and shrink your virtual disks.

Also note that the base disks can still be modified on the host if their `.vmdk` files are defragmented later, so before performing your initial backup, you should defragment the `.vmdk` files themselves through the VMware Workstation UI.

Your delta disks will naturally grow as you use the VM, install guest OS updates, etc.  At some point you can choose to take another snapshot (and separately choose whether to merge it with the previous snapshot).

Comment: just to confirm this approach: I've created a snapshot before i went to work in the VM for a day and the daily backup was down to 15 minutes... backup size went down to 8gb from the original 160gb. I'll have to keep an eye on this. Even if i create a snapshot once a month, that's still a very feasible approach!

Answer (score 0):

Check out
https://ultradefrag.net/handbook/v7/Introduction.html
It has an option to defragment a folder which could be helpful if you manage to move the relevant files into an folder so that you don't have to defragment the files individually one after another.

It might rearrange the file to your needs.

Otherwise you could try O&O Defrag which is commercial.

Answer (score 0):

First, defragment the files in the guest. Your options, which I recommend are:

1. `cmd.exe` -> `defrag /h /u /v c:`
2. UltraDefrag with only option <kbd>F6</kbd> - defragment

Then you need to fill the space that is taken by files that has moved. Old place of the files, before defragmentation, has data which is only occupying space, but file system has no interes in that space. To do that in guest:

Use Cygwin to fill empty occupied space, for example: `pv -B 1M < /dev/zero >> /cygdrive/c/fill.tmp`

or

Use SDelete from Windows Sysinternals: `sdelete -z c:\`

Then you can compact the virtual disk file on host:

```
"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifymedium --compact disk.vdi
```

If you have other type of virtual disks files, try to search for a tool that compacts that kind of virtual disk file.

For VMDK there are two options:

`vmware-vdiskmanager -k disk.vmdk`

or

`C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools>VMwareToolboxCmd.exe disk shrink disk.vmdk`

Answer (score 0):

Defragmentation will not help in your current setup, as
the last modification time on all the parts of a virtual disk will and
have always changed very time the virtual disk is accessed.

Even if you restructure the data so as to distribute it among several
virtual disks, the last modification time on all the disks will be
changed every time that the VM is used. So you will not gain
anything from it.

The only way to avoid backup up the entire VM every tine that it's used
is to restructure the virtual disk into several virtual disks and disable
the disks that you don't need before booting. Even worse, what you will
need to do is to remove the disk(s) you don't need from the VM before booting,
than add back when you do need it.

The above solution might be worse than the current situation...

Comment: I tried that and cannot verify. When I launch the VM (it's VMWare Fusion 12 in my case) I can see that initially only around 20 files change their modification date. During startup i can see that more and more files are touched. Once Windows is started up, all files were touched and the modification dates were spread over the 3-4 minutes.

Comment: This validates what I said. It's a limitation of using a VM, where any little change to the disk causes the disk file to be marked as modified by the host. In a real physical disk this wouldn't be happening, since a little change to the disk headers does not mark all the files as modified.